# Inserting page break to output cell from code

Tags: pdf-format, printing, pagelayout

I'm doing some calculations on a notebook, and then I print the results. All my code is written in a single cell. Later, I save the notebook as a **PDF file**.

I want the results to be grouped correctly, each on a different page.
Is there a way to print a page-break?

I want to do this in my code, and then to get every calculation in a different page. I searched the help, but I only found menu options to manually insert page break.

I've also seen that I could CreateDocument and maybe manipulate that, but I prefer doing it straight on the notebook I'm working on.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a pagebreak after each output cell, you can add CellPrint@Cell["", "PageBreak"]; after your Print statements as shown below:

```
Print@Sin@x;
CellPrint@Cell["", "PageBreak"]
Print@Cos@x;
```

Alternatively, you could redefine the Print function locally for your whole code block as follows:

```
With[{Print = (Print@#; CellPrint@Cell["", "PageBreak"])&},
...your code...
]
```

[image: "Example"]